# How to apply multiple conditions including Boolean operators to an ifelse statement

Tags: r

I need a little help here. I'd like to create a simple code rather than putting in multiple lines of code to get the same result

```
Discount <- NewORdersData %>%
     mutate(Discount = ifelse(Coupon == "OFF10" | "LARGE10", Sub_Total * 0.1, Sub_total * 0.05, Coupon))
```

i've been getting an error message  - Error in ifelse(Coupon == "OFF10" | "LARGE10", Sub_Total * 0.1, Sub_total *  :
unused argument (Coupon)

1. id like to create a new column in my data frame (Discount)
2. If value in the Coupon Column says OFF10 or LARGE10 - apply a 10% discount which would be(Subtotal *10%)
   if value in the Coupon Column says OFF5 - apply a 5% discount which would be (Sub_Total *10%)

```
dput(NewORdersData[1:10, "Coupon", drop = FALSE])
structure(list(Coupon = c("OFF10", NA, "LARGE10", "LARGE10", 
"LARGE10", "OFF10", "LARGE10", "LARGE10", NA, "LARGE10")), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")

dput(NewORdersData[1:10, "Sub_Total", drop = FALSE])
structure(list(Sub_Total = c(27.98, 28.9, 74.94, 91.85, 80.82, 
37.85, 48.8, 102.8, 12.95, 46.92)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this updated code

```
 NewORdersData %>%
 mutate(Discount = case_when(Coupon %in% c("OFF10", "LARGE10") ~ 0.1, Coupon == "OFF5" ~ 0.05, TRUE ~ 0) * Sub_Total)
```

Comment: Thank you, that works, although because the Coupon column has NA's the new Discount Column is not binding to the data frame. Would you know how to fix that?

Comment: @SusanMwansa Sorry I don't understand your problem. Can you perhaps show me the error message or at least a screenshot?

Comment: Hi @ekoam, sorry i meant to say do you know how to turn the NA's to 0
```
dput(NewORdersData[1:10, "Discount", drop = FALSE])
structure(list(Discount = c(2.798, NA, 7.494, 9.185, 8.082, 3.785, 
4.88, 10.28, NA, 4.692)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```